# How to change design according to screen size using NSLayoutConstraint in swift

Tags: swift, iphone, storyboard, size, nslayoutconstraint

I have designed a screen using Storyboard constraints for iPhone XR, but that design become big in iPhone7, so I want to change the height and width of my `ContainerView` using `NSLayoutConstraints`.

I have taken:

```
@IBOutlet weak var containerViewheight: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

This `ContainerView` actual height in iPhoneXR is 300, so I want to change it in iPhone7

For example:

```
if (iphone7) {
  self.containerViewheight.constant = 240
}

if (iphone SE) {
  self.containerViewheight.constant = 280
}
```

Unfortunately I have very little knowledge in size classes.

Comment: Sorry, i am quite confused, what are you trying to ask here? @swift

Comment: @jacob i have given leading, trailing, top, height constraints for containerView in iphonexr while designing  screen in storyboard.... but that view occupies more space in remaining iphone sizes so i want to change its height according to iphone sizes

Comment: Don't use constant constraints, use relative ones if you want them to change based on the screen size.

Comment: So let's make outlet references for your leading & trailing to adjust the width, then check to update the constant by device type. I recommend that you should change the constant based on percentage of the view width.

Comment: @jacob I'm able to get proper width bcs i have given leading and trailing but issue with height according to device type.. how can we change constant values according to device type... any code for that??

Answer (score 2):

You can always ask the `UIScreen` class method `main` for the current concrete size, it returns the concrete size of the current device.

```
let deviceSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
```

But you probably know, that `height` and `width` change depending on the orientation the device has (landscape or portrait).

Maybe this extension could help:

```
import UIKit

extension UIScreen {

    /// Retrieve the (small) width from portrait mode
    static var portraitWidth : CGFloat { return min(UIScreen.main.bounds.width, UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height) }

    /// Retrieve the (big) height from portrait mode
    static var portraitHeight : CGFloat { return max(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height)  }

    /// Retrieve the (big) width from landscape mode
    static var landscapeWidth : CGFloat { return max(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height) }

    /// Retrieve the (small) height from landscape mode
    static var landscapeHeight : CGFloat { return min(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height) }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate by knowing what ratio you want your container height to be of the screen height.

For eg: if `UIScreen.main.bounds.height` gives you 1000. And your appropriate container height here is 400. Then the required ratio of height of container to height of screen is 400/1000 or 2/5.

Now, what you can do is write

```
containerViewheight.constant = (2/5)*UIScreen.main.bounds.height
```